# how do I assign the typing of a super to the child constructor

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm looking for a way to pass on the typings of a parent's constructor parameters into the child's constructor, e.g.

```
class B extends A {    
    constructor (input) {
        super(input);
    }
}
```

I tried

```
class B extends A {    
    constructor (input : ConstructorParameters<typeof super>) {
        super(input);
    }
}
```

But I get an error from eslint `'super' is not defined.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to pass as `ConstructorParameters<typeof A>[0]` as a constructor param type.

```
class A {
  title: string;
  constructor(title: string) {
    this.title = title;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(title: ConstructorParameters<typeof A>[0]) {
    super(title);
  }
}
```

One more solution you can try suggested in comment:

```
  constructor(title: ConstructorParameters<typeof A>) {
    super(...title);
  }
```

Comment: You can also use  spread operator, it is more generic solution. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/m3a9kw)

Comment: Spread the argument could be more user friendly `constructor(...input: ConstructorParameters<typeof A>)`. We can do `new B(1)` instead of `new B([1])`

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't changing the constructor signature in the extending class, then this is one place where TypeScript *really shines* in terms of developer experience: You don't need to even include the constructor in your extended class, because TS does it for you!

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0CWA7ADgVwBcAuaCAgJ2wHMBuVdYAeyzPL2AMfIApt9jSFagEpE9dNAIALDBAB0fQtAC8mXITppoAX1S6UqUJBgAhaAFMAHgXNYAJjHgJ9qLOYDu0E92E1oAegAqaABRcnIuVAA9GNio1BDLHHMOcztoAEZoMHIqPABbWwIIABpoACMlKkYCaAAGOW4AJgBWFoAWUUD-VFcPL24AcnyATwBJdQJB3wD-aEYAa1QgA)

```ts
class A {
  input: string;
  constructor(input: string) {
    this.input = input;
  }
}

class B extends A {}

new B(); /* Error
^^^^^^^
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.(2554) */

new B('myInput'); // ok
```